# How to serialize the CBlock Class in C++ and print the hex to terminal?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind

I have tried to serialize as follows without success: bitcoin tag v22.0 from github.

In the file `src/miner.cpp` and the function

[`function std::unique_ptr<CBlockTemplate> BlockAssembler::CreateNewBlock(const CScript& scriptPubKeyIn)`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v22.0/src/miner.cpp#L102)

I have placed the line `std::cout << pblock << std::endl;` at the very end before it returns ([Here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v22.0/src/miner.cpp#L185)). The value that is printed to the terminal is:

`0x7fc9f4009410`

This is too little data, I would expect the entire block data to be serialized and printed in hex. What am I doing wrong? I know pblock is a pointer to a CBlock class, but it should still work.

What is the proper way to serialize CBlock data, and also the CBlockHeader data?

Thank you!

Comment: Since it is a `std::unique_ptr`, the `<<` operator outputs the pointer value rather than the object pointed to. Try dereferencing the pointer first.

Answer (score 2):

Since `pblock` is a pointer, you are printing an address. Dereference it to get the [format](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/a0988140b71485ad12c3c3a4a9573f7c21b1eff8/src/primitives/block.cpp#L16) you want:

```
std::cout << *pblock << std::endl;
```